# JavaFX TableView With SceneBuilder

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, tableview

I have a really simple class that takes a list of jobs and attempts to populate a TableView with them. I have this working without using FXML, but I am now trying new methods. The issue I have is that;

```
tView.getItems().addAll(jobList);
```

returns a null pointer, however if I create a new TableView there is no data in the table at all.

I believe that where I am going wrong is the use of the TableView that is constructed in SceneBuilderand not correctly initialising it, however I am confused in how I would do this. Here is my InterFace method class;

```
public class InterfaceMethods {

    @FXML TableView<Job> tView;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void populateTableView(Connection connection, Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Parent root;
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TableViewInterface.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        JobDataAccessor jobAccessor = new JobDataAccessor();
        final String query = "SELECT * FROM progdb.adamJobs";
        List<Job> jobList = jobAccessor.getJobList(connection, query);
        //System.out.println(query);
        //System.out.println(connection);
        tView.getItems().addAll(jobList);
    }
}
```

Here is my MainApp class;

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

private CheckUserDetails checkDetails;
private String pString, username = System.getProperty("user.name");
private InterfaceMethods iMethods;
private Connection connection;
@FXML private Button submitButton;
@FXML private PasswordField passField;
@FXML private Label warnLabel;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainInterface.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

@FXML
private void loginCheck() throws Exception {
    checkDetails = new CheckUserDetails();
    pString = new String();
    pString = passField.getText();
    System.out.println(pString);
    if (checkDetails.checkUserDetails(pString, username) != null) {
        setConnection(checkDetails.connection);
        handleTableView();
    } else {
        warnLabel.setVisible(true);
    }
}

@FXML
public void handleTableView() throws Exception {
    iMethods = new InterfaceMethods();

    Stage stage = (Stage) submitButton.getScene().getWindow();  

    connection = getConnection();

    iMethods.populateTableView(connection, stage);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Finally here is one of my two FXML files, the one with the TableView within it;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.InterfaceMethods">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tView" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="19.0" prefHeight="347.0" prefWidth="570.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="CaseNO." />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Case Notes" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Date Created" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Deadline" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Priority" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Completed" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The getJobList method (inside a different class);

```
    public List<Job> getJobList(final Connection connection, final String query) throws SQLException {
    try (Statement stmnt = connection.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(query);) {
        jobList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(connection);
        System.out.println(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            caseNumber = rs.getString("CaseNO");
            caseNotes = rs.getString("CaseNotes");
            dateCreated = rs.getString("DateCreated");
            deadlineDate = rs.getString("Deadline");
            prioritySetting = rs.getInt("Priority");
            completedSetting = rs.getString("Completed");
            job = new Job(caseNumber, caseNotes, dateCreated, deadlineDate, prioritySetting, completedSetting);
            jobList.add(job);
        }
        return jobList;
    }
}
```

Comment: The fx:id of TableView in FXML file should be the same as the name in conrtoller class, i.e. "tableView". Isn't it, check it?

Comment: It is definitely the same yes. I'll update the question with my controller class too.

Comment: extend the controller class with javafx.fxml.Initializableclass.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment @Hareesh, which class do you mean?

Comment: The NPE is at line tableView.getItems().addAll(jobAccessor.getJobList(connection, query));. So lets check the nullness of these variables: tableView, jobAccessor, connection and query. The only variable that should be null here is tableView, right? Track the usage of this variable where it can be null, may be you are assigning null somewhere.

Comment: When and where is the populateTableView() invoked?

Comment: I've printed connection, query and new jobAccessor is called so I can't see it being that. populateTableView() is invoked in my main Controller method. It's strange actually becuase the tableView is displayed, there just isn't any content in it. *hand to head moment* I probably should have seen that before.

Comment: Hmm so NPE had gone? And we are facing the next problem?

Comment: No it's still here. The TableView is displayed, with no content inside it (it should be populated by getJobList(), but there is still a NPE, I've changed a bit of my code for testing purposes, it is on the line `TableView.getItems().addAll(jobList);` which is slightly modified from the original question but the same problem applies. It must be the TableView because I have printed through jobList and it is not null nor empty.

Comment: @Uluk An update: When I call TableView TableView = new TableView(); there is no null pointer, the table appears but there is no data in the table at all. Also making changes to the table in scenebuilder (adding columns) to the default TableView makes no different to the table when running it, it still appears as the default table (two columns, C1, C2).

Comment: You must not init the fields annotated with @FXML yourself. Is the name of the field "TableView" or "tableView"? In fxml file?

Comment: @Uluk It is named TableView in the fxml file. Declared in my Java file as: `@FXML private TableView<Job> TableView;`. Taking out this line: `TableView.getItems().addAll(jobList);` successfuly creates the table, but of course with no data. Having that line uncommented results in the NPE. I printed the jobList and it definitely isn't null. There is no warning in eclipse in the fxml file saying it cannot find fx:id="TableView". Is the issue here the displaying of the list inside the table causing a NPE?

Comment: Well according to your above comment about no change on an adding column, implies you may have different fxml file and/or controller, or multiple controller instances where you use one but show aonther.

Comment: @Uluk I have MainApp.java which is the main controller for MainInterface.xml. I also have JobInterface.java which is the controller for TableViewInterface, which is attempting to populate a TableView with a MySQL query result. Unless I call TableView *namehere* = new TableView then I get the NPE in JobInterface.java

Comment: Can you update your question with recent code.

Comment: @UlukBiy, thanks for all your help. the original question has now been updated with complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to define the controller for your FXML.

For example your portion of FXML is:-

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="288.0" prefWidth="293.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
<children>
    <TableView fx:id="tableView" layoutX="35.0" layoutY="28.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="227.0">
    <columns>
        <!-- Columns for table view-->
    </columns>
    </TableView>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

1) Create a controller for your FXML page like:-

```
 fx:controller="com.code.Controller"
```

2) Now in your Controller, you can do like:-

```
package com.code;

    public class Controller implements Initializable {

        @FXML private TableView<User> tableView;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Amit. I've checked and my FXML already has a controller: `fx:controller="application.MainApp"` . Now In my controller (MainApp) I have: `@FXML private TableView<Job> tableView;` and then attempt to call the method.

Comment: @jbanks but it says that your conrtoller class name is "InterfaceMethods" in the question.

Comment: @Uluk Biy Apologies my mistake, the controller is indeed InterfaceMethods (I've tried a different controller, changed it back to fx:controller="application.InterfaceMethods" now), I am still getting the null pointer exception, it's getting rather frustrating acutally. Not too sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

All @FXML annotated fields of controller class are instantiated by the FXMLLoader while loading the fxml file having the `fx:controller` equal to that controller class or the class you set by fxmlLoader.setController(). If you instantiate the controller class yourself these @FXML annotated fields will be null. So here sample approach for using setController() instead of fx:controller in fxml file:

**MainApp**

```
public class MainApp extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception
    {
        MainController mainController = new MainController(getConnection());

        Scene scene = new Scene( mainController.getLayout() );

        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        launch( args );
    }
}
```

**MainController**

```
public class MainController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    private Parent layout;

    private Connection connection;


    public MainController(Connection connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getResource( "Main.fxml" ) );
        fxmlLoader.setController( this );
        try
        {
            layout = ( Parent ) fxmlLoader.load();
        }
        catch ( IOException exception )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( exception );
        }
    }


    public Parent getLayout()
    {
        return layout;
    }


    @FXML
    private void handleTableView( ActionEvent event )
    {
        InterfaceMethods iMethods = new InterfaceMethods( connection );
        label.getScene().setRoot(iMethods.getLayout());
        label.getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize( URL url, ResourceBundle rb )
    {
        // do work with @FXML annotated fields in here
        label.setText( "Initial data!");
    }

}
```

**Main.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleTableView" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**InterfaceMethods**

```
public class InterfaceMethods implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    TableView<Job> tView;

    private Parent layout;

    private Connection connection;


    public MainController( Connection connection )
    {
        this.connection = connection;

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getResource( "TableViewInterface.fxml" ) );
        fxmlLoader.setController( this );
        try
        {
            layout = ( Parent ) fxmlLoader.load();
        }
        catch ( IOException exception )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( exception );
        }
    }


    public Parent getLayout()
    {
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize( URL url, ResourceBundle rb )
    {
        // do work with @FXML annotated fields in here
        tView.setItems(...);
    }

}
```

Note that Main.fxml and TableViewInterface.fxml do not have `fx:controller` in it.

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand the issue, but I appreciate your help. I will continue to read tutorials and watch videos to hopefully understand this situation better.

Comment: The problem was iMethods = new InterfaceMethods(); in your code. You should use the FXMLloader and get the conrtoller instance from the fxmlloader instead of initiating it yourself, if you are using fx:conrtoller approach. If not then you can follow the approach as in my answer using setConrtoller() and init the conrtoller class yourself.

Comment: @jbanks, another problem is, in populateTableView() method you are loading "TableViewInterface.fxml" with fxmlloader. This will create new InterfaceMethods and fills its tView field, whereas the tView of the **current** instance will be null, and thats why NPE.

Comment: @jbanks, yes you need to read on FXML tutorials first, after that this discussions will be more clear.